# PayPal Python REST SDK returns 404 upon Payment.find()

Tags: python, paypal

At this point I'm not sure whether this is a problem on my end or on PayPal's. My customers have trouble paying using PayPal and the traceback that I get is coming out of my execute view:

```
  File "/somewhere/app/profile/views.py", line 652, in payment_paypal_execute
    payment = Payment.find(order.payment_id)
  File "/somewhere/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paypalrestsdk/resource.py", line 104, in find
    return cls(api.default().get(url))
  File "/somewhere/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paypalrestsdk/api.py", line 169, in get
    return self.request(util.join_url(self.endpoint, action), 'GET', headers=headers)
  File "/somewhere/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paypalrestsdk/api.py", line 98, in request
    return self.http_call(url, method, body=body, headers=http_headers)
  File "/somewhere/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paypalrestsdk/api.py", line 120, in http_call
    return self.handle_response(response, content.decode('utf-8'))
  File "/somewhere/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paypalrestsdk/api.py", line 139, in handle_response
    raise ResourceNotFound(response, content)
ResourceNotFound: Failed.  Response status = 404.  Response message = Not Found.
```

I do pretty much everything as per docs. I have a create view that creates the payment and saves the id in my database. Then the customer gets sent to PayPal to pay and returns using the referer. I then find the payment from my database and execute it.

The referer looks plausible:

```
HTTP_REFERER: https://www.paypal.com/il/cgi-bin/merchantpaymentweb?cmd=_flow&SESSION=somereallylongandsecretstring&dispatch=somereallylonghexstring
```

The request also looks good:

```
https://mystuff.com/somewhere/paypal/execute/<customer_user_id>?token=EC-SOMESTRING&PayerID=SOMEPAYPALID
```

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: It was eventually fixed by PayPal apparently. The API was quite unreliable for us in the beginning.